# android on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, noclassdeffounderror

I followed this  [link](http://www.unixmen.com/install-android-sdk-ubuntu-14-04/) to get android running on my Ubuntu 14.04

but when I ran android and I got this on my terminal

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/android/utils/ILogger     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 6 more

Comment: just a side info, why do not you go to official link and start from there http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: did that and android studio works like a charm when directory is shifted but the error is persistent when i run "android" on terminal

Comment: Ensure your env vars :  `export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools; export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home); export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH; export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: i have 
`export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle';
export ANDROID_HOME='/home/fsftn/Android/Sdk/';
export PATH=$PATH:'/home/fsftn/Android/Sdk/platform-tools':'/home/fsftn/Android/Sdk/tools'` on bashrc